# Rally API using Ruby: How do I reference the testcase method (Automated/Manual)?

Tags: ruby, rally

I am using Ruby to work with the Rally API. I am trying to reference the testcase method. The method being Manual or Automated, but I always get an error. I am using Ruby, so I don’t know if method is a reserved word in Ruby, or what is happening. Could you please let me know how to reference the test case method?

I am able to do:

testcase.objective

testcase.priority

etc.

But I can’t do

**testcase.method**

I always get this error.

‘method’: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)

Comment: Can you post a sample of your code and how you are querying for/populating the test case, and then how you reference its method attribute?

Comment: I think the problem is that the Ruby base object already has a function called method and it is trying to call that function instead of getting the value.

Comment: Interesting, sounds like a possible bug.

Comment: You should come back to up-vote and accept an answer. It helps you, those trying to answer your questions, and the community at large.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using rally_rest_api or rally_api?

If you are using rally_rest_api - Charles is correct.  try  testcase.elements[:method]
(fieldname downcased and underscored as a symbol)

If you are using rally_api - http://rubygems.org/gems/rally_api -
Getting fields can just be:
testcase["FieldName"]

Hope that helps.

Comment: side note - rally_api is a newer gem we plan to support going forward - should be a little easier to use and a lot faster on big queries.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to capitalize the names when trying to access built-in fields (i.e. fields that are *not* custom). I came across this problem myself and using `tc.Method` instead of `tc.method` fixed it.

The reason this error shows up can be seen in the docs for [Object#method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-method) which, as you've likely figured out by now, causes your code to call the method `method` instead of access the field named `method`.